# Laravel using Sum and Groupby

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6, laravel-collection

I would like to fetch sum of quantity in each month, so that I can display on bar chart quantities against month

This is what I thought but didn't workout

```
 $data1 = Borrow::groupBy(function($d) {
 return Carbon::parse($d->created_at)->format('m')->sum('quantity');
 })->get();
```

My table structure

```
Schema::create('borrows', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('member_id');
        $table->integer('book_id');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->integer('status')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Comment: your `quantity` field is type of string and you want to sum , it must be integer type?

Comment: yes it is integer type I copied wrong tale structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that a collection group by not an eloquent groupby

if you want to do it with eloquent, gotta:

```
 $data1 = Borrow::selectRaw('SUM(quantity) as qt, MONTH(created_at) as borrowMonth')
      ->groupBy('borrowMonth')->get();
```

if you want to do it with the collection groupBy method, you should first do the get, then the groupBy.

As in, though im not sure what you're trying to accomplish with what you do inside the callback..

```
 $data1 = Borrow::get()->groupBy(function($d) {
 return Carbon::parse($d->created_at)->format('m')->sum('quantity');
 });
```

Comment: Can you help on how can write my query

Comment: try that one, i think it should work for what you need

Answer (score 0):

try this query , you will get month wise count :

```
use DB;


 $month_wise_count=DB::table("borrows")
        ->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(MONTHNAME(created_at), "-",  YEAR(created_at)) AS month_year'),
                DB::raw("MONTH(created_at) as month , YEAR(created_at) as year"),
                DB::raw("(COUNT(*)) as total_records"),
                DB::row("(SUM('quantity') as total_value"))
        ->orderBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at),YEAR(created_at)"))
        ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at),YEAR(created_at)"))
        ->get();
```