# How to get all the sum of all the distinct items in MySQL in a single query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

How do I get the sum of all the distinct items? e.g. `0001 equals 10` and `0002 equals 10`.

What could be the best possible (MySQL or Laravel Query Builder) query on the sample data provided below.

**`tbl_transactions`** :

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| id    | item_code | quantity  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| 1     | 0001      | 6         |
| 2     | 0001      | 4         |
| 3     | 0002      | 7         |
| 4     | 0002      | 3         |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: use GROUP BY item_code   and SUM(quantity)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel using Sum and Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041367/laravel-using-sum-and-groupby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySQL, a basic `GROUP BY` query should work here:

```sql
SELECT item_code, SUM(quantity) AS total
FROM tbl_transactions
GROUP BY item_code;
```

Laravel code:

```php
$report = DB::table('tbl_transactions')
    ->selectRaw('item_code, SUM(quantity) AS total')
    ->groupBy('item_code')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I know it's a newbie question and I do hope that your answer will help other newbies too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this mysql

```
select item_code, sum(quantity) as sum
from tbl_transactions
group by item_code;
```

OR

```
DB::table('tbl_transactions')
            ->distinct('item_code')
            ->count('quantity');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this !!!

```
$report = DB::table('tbl_transactions')
->select([DB::raw("SUM(quantity) as sum"),'item_code']) 
->groupBy('item_code')
->get();
```