# How to sum value in laravel relational table column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

[image: eloquent query image here]

here I queried from productionActivity model and have relation with productionOutput model.
I want to sum *output_kg* in production_ouputs table from group by data.
i have try with withSum() function but it sum from single data not from all group by data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel using Sum and Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041367/laravel-using-sum-and-groupby)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to sum the output_kg from the production_outputs table grouped by some data (assuming it's on production_activity table). then the following should work if the groupBy() function is used correctly and the relationship between the models is defined correctly.

```
ProductionActivity::withSum('productionOutputs', 'output_kg')
        ->groupBy('column_to_group_by') // replace with actual column name
        ->get();
```